# How to delete all files into a subfolder of my custom module Prestashop

Tags: php, forms, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In my custom module, I'm unable to correctly delete all files contained in my folder `$upload_path = $this->local_path.'img/tmp/';` when calling the uninstall function.

Here it's my actual code :

```
    public function uninstall()
{
    $upload_path = $this->local_path.'img/tmp/';
    return parent::uninstall()
    && Configuration::deleteByName('N1_VERTICALSIDEMENU_ICONFILE');

    $files = glob($upload_path.'*'); // get all file names
    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
        if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
    }
}
```

I searched after a solution in official forum but without success

Any clue to do that ?

Comment: So what's the problem? Do you get an error message? Have you tried sending info to error log in your foreach loop? Maybe you should check if you have permissions to delete these files.

Answer (score 1):

Ok simply error of construction ...

I added the delete function too down in my code, and after putting before the return parent::uninstall() that's ok

Clean code =>

```
    public function uninstall()
{
    $upload_path = $this->local_path.'img/tmp/';
    $files = glob($upload_path.'/*');
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file);
    }
    return parent::uninstall()
    && Configuration::deleteByName('N1_VERTICALSIDEMENU_ICONFILE');
}
```